# How to use TypeOf with Include statment Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Following are my entity objects

```
public class Asset {...}
public class Picture : Asset {...}
public class Video : Asset {...}
public class Audio : Asset {...}

public class Project
{
 ...
 public ICollection<Asset> Assets{get;set;}
 ...
}
```

How can request `db.Projects.Include(x=>x.Assets.OfType<Picutre>());` using `Linq`, ie. to Query only Picture from List of Assets under Project.

Any Suggestions would help.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
var projects = from p in db.Projects
select new 
{
  Project = p,
  Pictures = p.Assets.Where(a => a is Picture)
}
```